# Translate PostgreSQL column names in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, internationalization

I have connected to PostgreSQL and imported the layer to QGIS.

The column names are written using English letters.

Can the names of columns be automatically translated to another language?

Comment: Why do you want to change column names?

Comment: For people who will work with them in QGIS. It'll be easier to understand what is this.

Comment: what locale is is the postgres DB in?

Comment: what locale is is the postgres DB in? – Mapperz
Sorry, but can you rewrite your question, I don't understand It, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the "Layer properties" and go to the "Fields" tab. You will see a column "Alias". Whatever you enter there will be used throughout the user interface.

Comment: Thanks, It's almost that I need. But If there are a lot of tables, It is not easy to rename each column.
I want it to make automatically. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You could write a script that updates the project file or a python plugin to automate the process. You could also open a feature request on [the issue page](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues) and ask for support of translation files for projects.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but perhaps this might help:

*Settings* > *Options* > *Locale*

[image]

---

EDIT:

The only other method I can think of is:

*Add Vector Layer* > *Encoding*

And select whichever one you think is suitable. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thank's, but it didn't help.

Comment: @bable, I've updated my post in the hope it might help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if You're trying to translate english names of columns into your local language automaticaly I think you can't do this in QGIS.

The only resolution that I mind is creating a view on database and show this view in QGIS

```
Create view translated_table as 
  select
    id as translated_id,
    field2 as translated_field2,
    ....
  from table
```

I'm only not sure if you can edit data via views, but if you only want to show it in QGIS this could be resolution.

Comment: If you have postgreSQL 9.3 you should create a materialized view. This way, your users will be able to do all crud (create/read/update/delete) operations.